# Why does my program keep creating new elements?

Tags: javascript, dom, checkbox

This is part of the interactivity of a form.

A user can select from a range of activities. 6 of the activities are priced as 100, one of them is priced at 200.

As the user checks the boxes, a label appears, telling the user what the total price is.

Right now, the price is being calculated fine.

But every single time a box is checked, a NEW label is added. As opposed to updating the old one. Why is this happening?

This is my code:

```
// Register for Activities section of the form.
document.querySelector(".activities").addEventListener("change", function(){
    var main = document.getElementById("all");
    var framework = document.getElementById("framework");
    var libs = document.getElementById("libs");
    var express = document.getElementById("express");
    var node = document.getElementById("node");
    var build = document.getElementById("build");
    var npm = document.getElementById("npm");

    // Calculate running total of price of events selected
    var mainPrice = 200;
    var otherPrice = 100;
    var totalPrice = 0;
    var totalLabel;


    if(!totalLabel){
        totalLabel = document.createElement('label');
        activities.appendChild(totalLabel);
    }

    if(main.checked == true){
        totalPrice += mainPrice;
    }
    if(framework.checked == true || express.checked == true) {
        totalPrice += otherPrice;
    } 
    if(libs.checked == true || node.checked == true) {
        totalPrice += otherPrice;
    } 
    if(build.checked == true) {
        totalPrice += otherPrice;
    } 
    if(npm.checked == true) {
        totalPrice += otherprice;
    }

    var totalNumber = totalPrice.toString();
    var totalText = "Total is $" + totalNumber;

    totalLabel.innerHTML = totalText;
});
```

I assumed this would be a problem before, I thought this would fix it by only creating a new element if `totalLabel` didn't already exist :

```
if(!totalLabel){
        var totalLabel = document.createElement('label');
        activities.appendChild(totalLabel);
    }
```

Any suggestions please guys?

Comment: simplest (not the best paradigm) change - totalLabel needs to be global ... better change, when creating totalLabel, give it a unique ID - check for the ID existing before creating the label

Answer (score 0):

You have a scoping problem.  totalLabel, as you create it, only lives inside the function.

Put a "var totalLabel" outside the function scope and lose the "var" from the if block.  So like:

```
var totalLabel;
document.querySelector...
```

Comment: Variables in JS are function-scoped, not block scoped. Your solution works, but the variable doesn't only exist inside the if block. It's simply recreated and discarded on every run.

Comment: Still a scoping problem; OP won't have the var on subsequent clicks since it's a new invocation.  Modified answer slightly to match.

Comment: Tried this, still having problems though

Comment: I'd pop an alert(totalLabel); right before the if and make sure it's empty the first time and populated subsequent times.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
var totalLabel;

totalLabel = document.createElement('label');
activities.appendChild(totalLabel);

document.querySelector(".activities").addEventListener("change", function(){
  // code

  // comment below code
  //if(!totalLabel){
  //  totalLabel = document.createElement('label');
  //  activities.appendChild(totalLabel);
  // }

  // code
});
```